# Problems inserting and retrieving last insert id using laravel 5 and sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, pdo, laravel-5

I have a table Person, that has a log trigger on it. When I save anything on Person table, the trigger insert a new row in another table called db_log.
So when I do:

```
$p = new Person;
$p->name = 'Anderson';
$p->save();
$p->id; //returning the log id, instead Person id.
```

I tested it using Sql Server Profiler, and the laravel was trying to retrieve the last insert using:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

When the correct way to get the last insert id could be:

```
SELECT COALESCE(scope_identity(), @@IDENTITY)
```

I'm using sql server 2012.

Can anyone help me with this problem please?
Thanks!

Comment: The coalesce is just in case scope_identify() returns nothing, so it will return the @@identity. My problem is: My person table has a trigger that when I insert a new person, the trigger insert a new row in another table. This way, laravel is returning the log table id instead person table id, when I ask for lastInsertId ($p->id).

Comment: But if scope_identity returns null that is because nothing in the current scope generated an identity value. In your case you do NOT want the value from @@identity as it is the incorrect value. You want scope_identity.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I want scope_identity, but laravel uses @@identity, and I can't change it. I can rewrite the framework code, but I don't wanna do it. I would like a way to retrieve the scope_identity from database without rewrite the framework method.

Comment: Wish I could help you there. I am a sql guy and don't know anything about laravel.